# Fix inefficient loop breaks post.php on form submit

Tags: loop, forms

As is, this loop works fine. Although I feel like its inefficient because it doesnt need to keep updating the nonce counter each time it loops, that only needs to be done once.

So when I try and move the UPDATE NONCE COUNTER code out of the loop or to a different part of the loop, it breaks the form processing with the error: **Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in /wp-includes/post.php on line 3371**

Original Loops:

```
/*********************/
/* PLAYING THE GAME. */
/*********************/



for ($a = 0; $a <= 1000; $a++) {

    /* UPDATE NONCE COUNTER */

    $current_nonce  = get_user_meta($player_id, 'nonce_counter', true);
    $new_nonce      = $current_nonce + 1;
    $update_nonce   = update_user_meta( $player_id, 'nonce_counter', $new_nonce);



    $game_string    = $player_string . "-" . $current_nonce;

    /* GAME HASH. */

    $game_hash      = hash_hmac('tiger128,4', $game_string, $server_key);

    /* GENERATE THE STARTING TOKEN COUNT                                                            */
    /* take the $game_hash and get the first 27 chars and convert that to a number to               */
    /* be used as the starting point for the game. The starting number must be larger than 99,999.  */
    /* the starting number is then reduced to a smaller number to be used for actual game play.     */

    $game_hash_string   = substr($game_hash,0,27);
    $game_hash_value    = intval($game_hash_string);    


    if ($game_hash_value > 99999) {

        $game_start_value = $game_hash_value;


        for($i = $game_start_value; $i >= 1; $i-=4) { 


            $winning_number = $i;

        }

        break;

    }

}
```

I feel like a better version of this should be something like this:

```
/*********************/
/* PLAYING THE GAME. */
/*********************/



for ($a = 0; $a <= 1000; $a++) {


    /* GENERATE THE STARTING TOKEN COUNT                                                            */
    /* take the $game_hash and get the first 27 chars and convert that to a number to               */
    /* be used as the starting point for the game. The starting number must be larger than 99,999.  */
    /* the starting number is then reduced to a smaller number to be used for actual game play.     */

    $game_hash_string   = substr($game_hash,0,27);
    $game_hash_value    = intval($game_hash_string);    


    if ($game_hash_value > 99999) {

    /* UPDATE NONCE COUNTER */

    $current_nonce  = get_user_meta($player_id, 'nonce_counter', true);
    $new_nonce      = $current_nonce + 1;
    $update_nonce   = update_user_meta( $player_id, 'nonce_counter', $new_nonce);


    // GAME STRING //
    $game_string    = $player_string . "-" . $current_nonce;

    /* GAME HASH. */

    $game_hash      = hash_hmac('tiger128,4', $game_string, $server_key);

        $game_start_value = $game_hash_value;


        for($i = $game_start_value; $i >= 1; $i-=4) { 


            $winning_number = $i;

        }

    }

}
```

where it only update the nonce after the starting number has been determined. but when i try to do this, i get the error: **Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in /wp-includes/post.php on line 3371**

Comment: Can you explain why the user meta is updated on every loop iteration rather than once at the very end after the loop? Looking at that line in `wp-includes/post.php` indicates there is no call to `array_filter` on or near those lines. Have you modified WordPress core? Can you confirm you're using the latest available version?.I suspect the issue is related to code that happens after or before this, that has not been included in the question, a call to `wp_insert_post`